# Can't get an answer to which android version will support chromecast app

Tags: android, chromecast

I don't understand why I'm have such a hard time finding an answer to what seems like a simple, straightforward question.

I just bought chromecast dongle and want to control the device from my android phone. Its a trivial task, i know because I setup my windows 8 tablet to do this. The only problem is I have an old 2010 htc phone running froyo. When i go to google play I don't see the chromecast app, which I assume is because it won't run on froyo. Hence my question - what is the minimum OS requirement to run chromecast app. Somehow this basic info is not readily accessible.

Would appreciate anybody who could clue me in. Am i missing something simple? What's the deal?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it says very clearly on the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app that

Requires Android
2.3 and up

So, that would be Gingerbread and above.

HTH

Comment: Oops sorry, you know I actually forgot that i had that piece of info. It just got lost in my mind because I am relatively inexperienced with android. So I started studying up on it and amidst the info overload I just simply forgot the obvious and the obvious place to find it. Btw, out of curiosity, I thought it would take more of an egregious offense to get a negative rating for a question, no? I am new to this site as well.

Comment: @user2722568 Sometimes, folks tend to be very critical :) It was not me that downgraded or gave a negative rating. I will upvote it once so that you don't appear too bad. Rookie mistake but definitely don't post here unless you have done ur homework. :)

Comment: Thanks, I kind of guessed it wasn't you :) Appreciate the advice as well.